# Spring JpaRepository using generic entity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, generics, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to implement a generic DAO like this to use it with X Entities quite similar (id, code, description):

```
@Repository
public interface GenericDao<T> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {

    T findByCode(String code);
    T findById(Long id);
}
```

One of my Entities is like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
public class Test {...}
```

I've got a Service where I need to use the Dao:

```
@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

    private GenericDao<Test> testDao;

    @Autowired
    public TestServiceImpl(GenericDao<Test> testDao) {
        this.testDao = testDao;
    }
}
```

When I start my application using SpringBoot the application doesn't start and the error is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error     creating bean with name 'genericDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class java.lang.Object
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1127)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1044)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class java.lang.Object
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:219)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:68)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getMetadata(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:67)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:145)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:89)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:69)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:172)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:239)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:225)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
... 34 more
```

Comment: its called type erasure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this.
Spring trying to create your repository **on start**, not on autowiring moment. But Spring absolutely has no idea, what kind of generic param it should to use. So it is trying to instantiate this repository with `Object`. But `Object` is not entity, so you get corresponding error.

Conclusion: you repository must be of specific type, but not generic.

Comment: You are right ! I tried to make this update: `@Repository
public interface GenericDao<T extends BaseEntity> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {

    T findByCode(String code);
    T findById(Long id);
}`. I've created a `@Entity public abstract class BaseEntity {...}` and all my entities extend that class. The application starts but I've got a problem with Hibernate because logicaly it's not a real table on DB

Comment: @nicola try to mark your abstract base class with MappedSuperclass annotation.

Answer (score 5):

You can do what you're trying to accomplish with some tweaks.

Instead of marking your GenericDao with @Repository and using it as such, use the [@NoRepositoryBean](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/NoRepositoryBean.html) annotation instead. As the JavaDocs state, Spring JPA will try to initialize anything attached to the JpaRepository, but the @NoRepositoryBean allows you to create intermediate extensions that won't be initialized that your real repositories can extend from. You just have to ensure that anything that implements your GenericDao class does provide a parameter for T.

This means you must also implement extensions of GenericDao that actually will have the @Repository annotation, and you use those daos in place of generic in your service. So your code will look like this:

Generic Dao:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface GenericDao<T> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {

    T findByCode(String code);
    T findById(Long id);
}
```

TestDao, a new class you'll add which is the parameterized implementation:

```
@Repository
public interface TestDao extends GenericDao<Test> {

}
```

And the Service:

```
@Service
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

    private TestDao testDao;

    @Autowired
    public TestServiceImpl(TestDao testDao) {
        this.testDao = testDao;
    }
}
```